# Gitlab CI setup error - Could not find a JavaScript runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to setup Gitlab CI for my Ruby on Rails project, but ran into an error that I don't know how to fix.

The application is running on Ruby 2.3.1, Rails 5.0 and is using a postgreSQL database.

My current .gitlab.ci.yml file looks like this:

```
# https://hub.docker.com/r/library/ruby/tags/
image: "ruby:2.3.0"

# Pick zero or more services to be used on all builds.
# Only needed when using a docker container to run your tests in.
# Check out: http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#what-is-service
services:
  - redis:latest
  - postgres:latest
  - node:latest

# This is a basic example for a gem or script which doesn't use
# services such as redis or postgres
before_script:
  - gem install bundler         # Bundler is not installed with the image
  - bundle install -j $(nproc)  # Install dependencies

rubocop:
  script:
  - rubocop

rspec:
  script:
  - rspec spec

rails:
  script:
  - rails db:migrate
  - rspec spec
```

So it's supposed to be using NodeJS as runtime. However, I get the following error:

```
$ rails db:migrate
rails aborted!
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'.
Gem Load Error is: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/usr/local/bundle/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:58:in `autodetect'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/uglifier-3.0.0/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: Have you installed NodeJS on your system though? What system is this on?

Comment: @miccet This is the system: https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-ci/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to have a javascript runtime (e.g. nodejs). You can install it by using the following command:

**For Ubuntu Users**

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

**For CentOS / RedHat Users**

```
sudo yum install nodejs
```

In case you can't install `nodejs` you can install and then use `therubyracer` gem.

Description from repository:

> Embed the V8 JavaScript interpreter into Ruby.

Add this line to your `Gemfile`

```
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
```

Comment: Everything has to be defined in this file. As you can see it's using docker packages to setup the environment. The above is ofc valid for a system that you have real access to, which is not really the case for this CI server (https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-ci/).

Comment: @Severin as i understand `docker services` its a self-contained instances, but you need `nodejs` on instance with rails

Comment: Yes. Problem is though, that you can't run those setup commands on Gitlab CI as you have shown above. So simply adding it to the `before_script` section will give you an error. How do you suppose it can be setup in this environment?

Comment: @Severin hm, i see two ways: 1) Adding `gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby` into `gemfile` 2) Edit `dockerfile`

Comment: Adding `gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby` fixed this particular issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Gitlab-CI can be configured with the file `.gitlab-ci.yml` in this case:

```
before_script:
- apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev nodejs
```

can be used to install `nodejs` on the setup stage ([source](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/quick_start/)).

A complete `before_script` with jekyll can look like the following code (for instance, this is required for jekyll-minifier):

```
image: ruby:latest

variables:
  JEKYLL_ENV: production
  LC_ALL: C.UTF-8

before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev nodejs
  - ruby -v
  - which ruby
  - gem install bundler
  - bundle install

test:
  stage: test
  script:
  - bundle exec jekyll build -d test
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - test
  except:
  - master

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - bundle exec jekyll build -d public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```